# Would it be possible to have Stack Exchange alter this site's features to avoid spoilers?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, spoilers

This site seems to bring with it a special issue: When asking a question both the suggested questions and sidebar are practically designated spoiler flashes. It's very difficult, when the content is targeted to the story you're asking about, in places where it's designed to be seen first, not to be in danger of glimpsing a peek at potentially massively horrific spoilers in questions titles.

Would it be possible to have Stack Exchange alter the behavior of certain features to avoid these spoilers? For example, have the suggested questions that appear when writing a question be collapsed at first?

Comment: If you don't want a story "spoiled", then... Don't read about it on The Internet until you're done reading/watching it! If you assume that the only way to properly enjoy the story is to find out details in the exact order that the author(s) intended, you can't be asking questions mid-way through... Alternately, if you want your reading/watching experience enhanced by the sort of perspective only The Internet can provide, then just embrace it and stop worrying.

Comment: In other words "We don't care about user experience of people who like you who have questions about things that occur in the middle of anime series, but don't want major events to be spoiled while asking the question. Instead, you should make a mental note of all questions and save them for months from now when you finish the series." In other words, this is a site for people who have finished watching the entire series or dont care about major events being spoiled while asking the question. Thanks for that info Shog.

Comment: I care a lot about you, Viz. But caring doesn't let me look into your mind and separate the details you're interested in knowing early from the *extremely-similar* details that you'd rather not know early. Spoilers are largely a personal matter; as you can see from the linked duplicate, folks here will *try* to avoid major plot events when possible, but ultimately what you find spoiling is up to you...

Comment: @Shog9 You're a smart man Shog, I've read some things you've written across the network, and Im sure you'll have a response that sounds great, to anything I say, but the fact is, I just asked about a UX improvement, and you immediately put a big red stamp on it and said "Sorry, but you just need to deal with the spoilers, or dont ask questions here. We cant avoid spoilers." - But by making the question suggestions a collapsed list, you could actually help not spoil series for people curious about certain details mid-way through.

Comment: I would dare to estimate that a massive portion, 90% or more, of the questions asked on this site are asked while people are watching or reading a series, not after they're done. Avoiding spoilers somewhat, in the way I suggested, wouldn't be very hard for your team, and I find it interesting that you would so quickly shoot such an idea down, without even entertaining thought on such a feature. "Deal with spoilers or dont use this site." Isn't the most effective way for a person such as yourself to handle feature requests on a site such as this one.

Comment: And we could also ruin the experience for folks searching for an answer. And create more duplicates. Neither is ideal for a site dedicated to dissemination of information. I can sympathize with you, but what you want runs counter to the core goals of both this site and Stack Exchange as a whole.

Comment: @Shog9 And that's a fair enough answer. I wasn't looking for sympathy, only solutions. There was a problem with the solution I suggested, I'm fine with that. I only took issue in the reasoning you provided.